# Light CMS update edits in file with PHP

Tags: php, content-management-system, light

Some examples of "light" content management systems:

- [CushyCMS](http://www.cushycms.com)
- [Surreal CMS](http://surrealcms.com)
- [Unify](http://unify.unitinteractive.com)

What they have in common is that you just add a specific classname to the parts of your webpage that you want to make editable.
In the backend they somehow save the edited snippets back to the file you edited (no database).

Example of original content and edited content:

**Original HTML code**

```
<div class="editable">

<ul>
<li>an</li>
<li>unordered list</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

**Edited HTML code**

```
<div class="editable">

<ol>
<li>an</li>
<li>ordered list</li>
</ol>

</div>
```

The frontend is pretty clear to me but how would I best go about the backend (PHP)?

I need to make sure that dynamic PHP code keeps working, so I can't just update the complete file.

Any resources or pointers are very welcome since I have searched for this technique but couldn't find any in depth ideas or methods of doing this.
The light content management systems listed above aren't open source so learning from the source is not an option either.

**EDIT**

I stated that I don't want to use PHP DOM but things have changed. Both Surreal CMS and CushyCMS are using it, which is a good indicator it is the way to go.

The problem I am experiencing with PHP DOM is that I can't replace **only** the part of the original document the user edited.
When loading the original file, **PHP DOM will do unwanted things** to the document like changing the meta tag, converting single quotes to double quotes, ...
Now, for the edited part this is fine, but it is unacceptable for the rest of the document since that should remain untouched (the user didn't edit this, right).

Cushy and Surreal both seem to know how to stop PHP DOM from touching the rest of the document but I don't. So if you know, let me know.

Comment: Well, the problem is that there are countless ways how you can do this.

Comment: @Adrian What would be the best way? To filter, I could define some further requirements: no saving to a text file, saved content must remain its formatting (so no PHP DOM Document), secure.

Comment: Have you solved the problem of how to keep the PHP code intact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You question is a little vague, but maybe this will help you:

### Part A: Editing

To edit your lightweight pages, you have to inject some javascript into the page. This javascript searches for all elements with "editable" class and sets them to editable (have a look at the [contentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.contentEditable) property for this as a very basic starting point).

Keep some identification of the edited element, for example the id, the xpath or the index. To save the texts, just ajax them to your server.

### Part B: Saving to the file

You might store the pieces in a database, but I assume you want to change the file directly. To do this, you just replace the content of each of the elements with what you received via AJAX. To find the elements in the sourcecode, you will have to use something like PHPs SimpleDOM (this also implies that the HTML pages are valid XHTML).

Just find the element, write the changes, write the file, done.

Note, however, that things will become much more complicated if you want to make it work for real projects.

**EDIT:** just saw your "PHP code has to keep on working" part of the question. Consider some regular expression magic for this one - replace each `/(<?.*?>)/` with a  text placeholder (for example "-PHPCODE-$i-") and after updating the dom tree, replace these placeholders back. Either way, a hard job.

Comment: A good direction you've set here. Maybe my question is a little bit vague but your answer isn't. I will try some stuff and will let you know if there's something unclear.

Comment: Did some tests with PHPQuery. Your steps are working out fine. However, CushyCMS and Surreal CMS only use PHP DOM manipulation on the editable region, not the whole document. How do I know? Because HTML attributes with single quotes are converted to double quotes for the editable part of the document and they aren't for the rest of the document. Do you know how they do that?

Comment: I'd assume they resort to regular expression magic to leave out the rest of the page. Using PHPQuery sounds like a cool approach though.

Comment: @SteffenMüller: There is a problem with your edit though: what if the OP wants to edit the executed / included PHP code output? Replacing back and forth with obscure identifiers will preserve the original PHP code but will also invalidate client-side changes.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too vague for a best way and my way may be one good way in 10 good ways and they all are still not the best way. For some, my way will even be one in 100 bad ways.

About this `class="editable"` attribute: You cannot use these server-side with PHP. I don't know these lightweight CMS but they are probably using Javascript/AJAX which targets the class and probably adds an edit button.

**UDPATE** Ah look indeed, these "light CMS" change the webpage file. Well here's the thing. These are not CMS but online HTML editors. In this case the **best** thing is DOM Document which for some reason you don't want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Like I said, the frontend is pretty clear to me. Just some AJAX sending the snippet that needs to be updated to the backend. Maybe you could give me just one way, doesn't matter if it's the best or worst, so I will at least get an idea of how to do this? The only idea I got now is using a regex.

Comment: For some things you might use regex but for changing a list from `ol` to `ul` you only need one bit; true for `<ol>` and false is `<ul>`. That's all you send and your PHP code somehow has to understand it. The info is stored in some data storage.

Comment: FYI: About learning from the source: Download Wordpress and see how that works for you.

Comment: @Andrian the list is just an example, it can be any content. Learning from the Wordpress source won't really help me since it saves to a database, not to the webpage file.

Comment: Ah, you really think or believe your CMS examples save changes to the webpage file.

Comment: Well at least I really know that Surreal CMS does that because when I download a file via FTP, edited with Surreal CMS, all the changes are in the file. Unify doesn't use a database.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to edit just a few texts, there is new very simple CMS utility - [Minorit](http://www.minorit.com). It is possible to use it on old websites with no logic changing, no instalation.